# How to remove installed app in Wildfly 9

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

My Wildfly 9 server does not start because it is accessing a link that does not exists anymore.

I fixed the link to point to the latest working link.

My problem is... my wildfly server does not start and I do not know how to replace the WAR file.

I wanted to remove the installed application IyotBihagay so that my wildfly server will start and I can do redeploy again with the corrected wsdl link.

/var/log/wildfly/console.log

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl?wsdl

    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:275)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:363)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:321)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:207)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:114)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at com.amadeus.xml.AmadeusWebServices.<init>(AmadeusWebServices.java:47)
    at com.iyotbihagay.service.SaksakBilatServiceImpl.<init>(SaksakBilatServiceImpl.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 24 more

[0m[31m23:15:46,927 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "IyotBihagay.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./IyotBihagay" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./IyotBihagay: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'saksakBilatServiceImpl' defined in \"/content/IyotBihagay.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/iyotbihagay/service/SaksakBilatServiceImpl.class\": Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.iyotbihagay.service.SaksakBilatServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl?wsdl

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'saksakBilatServiceImpl' defined in \"/content/IyotBihagay.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/iyotbihagay/service/SaksakBilatServiceImpl.class\": Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.iyotbihagay.service.SaksakBilatServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl?wsdl

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.iyotbihagay.service.SaksakBilatServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl?wsdl

    Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iyotbihagay.com/wsdl/saksak_bilat_consume.wsdl?wsdl
"}}
[0m[0m23:15:46,972 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "IyotBihagay.war" (runtime-name : "IyotBihagay.war")
[0m[0m23:15:46,973 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./IyotBihagay: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./IyotBihagay: Failed to start service

[0m[0m23:15:47,143 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
[0m[0m23:15:47,143 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
[0m[31m23:15:47,144 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 15362ms - Started 782 of 839 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 103 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
[0m
```

I think my wildfly is configured or installed as stand-alone.

Comment: If you are running in standalone mode you can probably simply remove it from the list of deployments at the end of the standalone.xml file.

Comment: Thanks dude, removing the deployment [IyotBihagay] in the deployments nodes of standalone-full.xml did the trick. Thanks again dude.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've solved your problem, but for others that may want to do this.

In WildFly 9+ CLI has an [offline CLI mode](http://wildfly.org/news/2015/03/13/Offline-CLI/). You should be able to use this to undeploy the deployment.

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh
```

Example CLI commands

```
embed-server
undeploy IyotBihagay.war
stop-embedded-server
```

In WildFly 9 you can only use a standalone server. In WildFly 10 the same would also work for a managed domain with the `embed-host-controller` command.

Comment: Just to note: it might not actually work for the OP, the logging seems to indicate that he's actually running Wildfly 8.2.0.

Comment: Good point. The subject said WildFly 9 and I didn't look closely enough at the final log message.